# Apache request header missing Host:, need to process request

Tags: apache, http

I have several devices with a tiny http client on them.  We tested them with my custom webserver and all is good.  Now I want to migrate to apache as my webserver, and my requests are getting shut down:

client sent HTTP/1.1 request without hostname (see RFC2616 section 14.23)

I know this error occurs because I'm missing the "Host: www.blah.com" entry in my header.  It's required per HTTP 1.1 spec

RFC2616 section 14.23
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

The issue is I cannot change the firmware on the hardware, so the http client is what it is.  If I were familiar with this requirement before hand, I would have implemented it.  My question is:

How can I configure apache (I think the authz_host module ) to allow requests with no Host: entry in their header?

Comment: Similar to [Can Tomcat accept HTTP 1.1 requests without a Host header?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12808451/can-tomcat-accept-http-1-1-requests-without-a-host-header).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direct answer is that I do not think you can make apache ignore the protocol.  Your clients are broken.  However, thinking outside the box a bit, if all else fails, perhaps you could write a small http proxy in python which does nothing but fix your http requests and send them on to the proper host and tell your clients to use the proxy.

Comment: Ya, I was thinking about writing an app to fix and redirect the request.  More than likely I would just adjust the client to use a different port, which I can configure on them through a settings file.  Then create a service to  fix and redirect to the apache port

Comment: If my comment is useful, consider upvoting me.  ;-)

Comment: It appears I can't unless my rep is >= 15

Comment: Wow you cannot vote for my answer?  Oh, well, I hope you get an answer you can "accept" then.

Comment: Aha, thanks for accepting my answer.  Hope that workaround works for you.

Comment: I managed to convince the team to do another round of testing with the new code, this time with a Host entry!  Sticking to specs does wonders